# CSS to dynamically create columns

Tags: css, dynamic-columns

I have three `<div>` elements:

```
<div class="foo">A</div>
<div class="foo">B</div>
<div class="foo">C</div>
```

#### Desired behavior

I'd like to write some CSS to create the following effect as the screen size changes:

[image]

#### Undesired behavior

I know how to implement the following (undesired) behavior:

[image]

```
div.foo {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 300px;
}
```

Is there a simple way (pref. without any Javascript library) to achieve my desired behavior that will work on major browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE9+)?

Comment: Hmm... so you want a vertical layout on smaller screens and a horizontal layout on wider screens? Are there an arbitrary amount of divs? If not, you could do some manual placement with media queries and CSS transforms.

Comment: Ooo, what about CSS columns? I don't think it would work on <IE10, but perhaps that could get a nice effect.

Comment: Just those three divs. Yes, I was thinking media queries. Do I need to surround A and B with a `<div>` do you think so I can control their combined layout?

Comment: Well CSS columns would be the "cleanest" way to do it, but seeing as you want as much support as possible, placing A and B in a parent div would be the best bet. Keep in mind, though, that media queries are not supported by <IE9, so you would indeed require some JavaScript to achieve the same effect in IE8 (perhaps using Modernizr).

Comment: All depends on what your definitions of Medium and Small are, here's a super barebones version http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/cpwoj with media queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the A and B into it's own container.

```
<div class="foo-wrap">
    <div class="foo">A</div>
    <div class="foo">B</div>
</div>
<div class="foo">C</div>
```

Then use a media query to control the display of the A/B column on smaller screens:

```
.foo-wrap {
    display: inline-block;
}

div.foo {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   width: 300px;
}

@media all and (max-width: 925px) {
    .foo-wrap {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

**Demo:**  http://jsfiddle.net/axertion/j48da85n/1/

Comment: Thank you! That's just what I was after.

Comment: By the way, I used `max-width: 925px` on the max-width to account for the additional space between the blocks.  Since you are using `display: inline-block;`, there will be some additional space between the blocks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without an extra wrapper div and a media query.

HTML:

```
<div class="box-wrap">
  <div class="box">a</div>
  <div class="box">b</div>
</div>
<div class="box">c</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.box-wrap {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

@media (min-width: 900px) {
  .box-wrap {
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/sdsanders/pen/zLFJj

Comment: Thanks! Actually because of the border you put on the boxes if you hover +/- a pixel or two around the 900px mark the top row shows AB instead of AC. Is there a way to make that require less exactness?  E.g. could we use `max-width` instead?