# CSS dynamic positioning of 6 blocks

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I just asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190949/css-to-dynamically-create-columns) concerning the dynamic CSS positioning of three blocks as the screen size changes. I tried to simplify the situation before I posted and now I feel an idiot because I've just realised that what I actually need is six blocks:

[image]

```
<div class="block">A</div>
<div class="block">B</div>
<div class="block">C</div>
<div class="block">D</div>
<div class="block">E</div>
<div class="block">F</div>
```

The [3 block solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25190949/css-to-dynamically-create-columns) doesn't work here because I can't wrap A+B, C+D, E+F in divs and also wrap A+B+C and D+E+F. It would require overlapping `<div>`s. What do I do? Please help!

My ideal solution would be pure CSS (media queries) or minimal Javascript (pref. no libraries).

---

**EDIT:** To be clear, what I'm after is a solution that **dynamically changes the layout** of the boxes (as per the diagram above) when the screen width changes.

Also, I **don't** want:

```
AB       ABC
CD       DEF
EF
```

Comment: I shared one before - but this still works if you keep adding boxes - http://codepen.io/evanrbriggs/pen/cpwoj Is there a set width on these boxes?

Comment: Aren't using bootstrap by any chance?

Comment: @Evan, The order of those blocks in your code isn't the way I want it. I don't want AB across the top.

Comment: @j08691, er, no. Why?

Comment: Just thinking that if you were it might be easier to solve.

Answer (score -1):

What about using Bootstrap's or Foundation's grid system?

If bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="block">A</div>
        <div class="block">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="block">C</div>
        <div class="block">D</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <div class="block">E</div>
        <div class="block">F</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the screen to change dynamically, not just position things in a fixed grid.